# How to reactively update the dataframe?

Tags: python, shiny-reactivity, py-shiny

Is there a way to reactively update the dataframe of my plotly widget by using `ui.input_select`?

When I run the following code I get a type error from the dataframe being selected:

```
def my_widget():
    fig = px.bar(data.input(), x='Date', y='Value', color='Type', barmode='stack', text='Value')
```

Here's a look at my input_select as well. The error seems to occur when having a dataframe as a parameter instead of a string.

```
ui.input_select(
    "data", label="Data Type",
     choices=[exercise_df_melted, education_df_melted]
)
```

Is there a workaroud to avoid type errors?

I've tried using a dictionary instead of a list to capture the input. Had no success.

Comment: The issue you're facing is that you're passing actual dataframes exercise_df_melted and education_df_melted as choices to the ui.input_select function, and later, you're trying to use the selected choice as a dataframe directly in the px.bar function. This approach won't work because Plotly's px.bar expects a dataframe as input, not a choice object.

To dynamically update the dataframe used in your Plotly widget based on the selection from ui.input_select, you should define a callback function that updates the figure when the selection changes.